# How can i prove this sum of factorials?

Tags: calculus, factorial, trigonometric-series

i was messing around whith some trig identities and i came across this equation:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{(2k)!(2(n-k)+1)!}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\quad\quad(1)$$
This formula becomes pretty when choosing a value for n. Let n be 2, it gives:
$$\frac{1}{0!\;5!}+\frac{1}{1!\;4!}+\frac{1}{2!\;3!}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2^5}{5!}$$
The reason this happens is due to the trigonometric identity
$\cos(x)\sin(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)$, expanding in Taylor series both sides:
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty\left(\frac{(-1)^{i}}{(2i)!}x^{2i}\right)\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(\frac{(-1)^{j}}{(2j+1)!}x^{2j+1}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)!}(2x)^{2n+1}\right)$$
expandind the left hand side and grouping by the powers of x leads to equation (1).

Is it possible to find another proof of this identity (maybe without reliying on trig id.)?

Comment: Try evaluating $(1+1)^{2n+1}+(1-1)^{2n+1}$ in two ways, one following the order of operations and two using the [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)

Comment: Multiplying both sides by $(2n+1)!,$ this can be written as $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n+1}{2k}=\frac12\cdot 2^{2n+1}.$$

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Indeed !!!

Comment: You actually have the stronger identity, not just for the odd case: $$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor} \binom m{2k}=\frac12\cdot 2^m.$$ For $m>0.$ When $m=2n+1,$ you have your result.